# How to run Unwise.exe silently while specifying log file

Tags: batch-file, uninstallation, wise

This may be a dumb question with a simple solution but I am trying to incorporate a line in a batch file to silently uninstall a wise uninstaller (it's to uninstall SolidThinking Embed 2017).

There is a shortcut for the Unwise.exe in the same folder to also include the log file from installation, otherwise running it by itself will prompt for a log file, or it throws the error that it cannot find the log if done in the script.

Is there a way to include the log file in the line and also uninstall the application silently?

For example (which doesn't work):

```
"C:\hw2017\Unwise.exe" "C:\hw2017\VisSimECDWeb150.log" /S
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The vendor of the application can answer that for you.

Comment: You're looking for a way to automatically fill in a prompt, am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Did you try running `C:\hw2017\Unwise.exe /?` ?

Comment: Right click on the shortcut and look at how it calls the program.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't use a file named `install.log`? I'd suggest using `Start /D C:\hw2017 UnWise.exe install.log /S`. If the log file is really named like that use `Start /D C:\hw2017 UnWise.exe VisSimECDWeb150.log /S`. There appear to be many issues with Wise uninstaller not picking up the log file, so you may have to forget about the silent option and point the uninstaller to the log file when prompted.

Comment: Vendor was unfortunately unaware of how to do this, they suggested creating a response file which also did not work. It's not to fill in a prompt it's just being able to incorporate the log file while running silently. /? simply launches the .exe while throwing the error "Could not open install.log" The log file is named the one in my example line above which throws it off seemingly, I'd rather keep the name as is. I did try your line, @Compo, but it failed. Going to give up on the silent aspect, I really appreciate everyone's help/input though.

Comment: The only solution to this that I've seen before is that the log file is copied or moved to a different location. When the prompt asks for the location, point it to the copied/moved one. As I said, it's an issue with the Wise software, and unfortunately there's nothing much else that I can recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/wisescript-command-line-options. Note the final paragraph which has specific instructions for how to specify the log file.

> **Uninstall Command Line Options**
>
> You can apply the following command line options to the WiseScript
>   Express uninstall executable file, unwise.exe or unwise32.exe.
>
> `/Z` Removes empty directories, including the one containing Unwise.
>
> `/A` Automatic mode. The Wise splash screen appears on the destination
>   computer, and the uninstall proceeds immediately with no end user
>   choices, except for questions about uninstalling shared files.
>
> `/S` Silent mode. The uninstall proceeds silently with no splash screen,
>   no dialogs, and no end user choices.
>
> `/R` Rollback mode.
>
> `/U` Removes the Select Uninstall Method dialog, which means the end
>   user does not see options for a custom, automatic, or repair
>   uninstall.
>
> When you use command line options for the uninstall
>   program, you must send it the path to the log file as a parameter. It
>   must be the log file that is in the same folder as unwise.exe. If the
>   path to the log file contains spaces, it must be surrounded by
>   quotation marks.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files\Application\UNWISE.EXE" /A "C:\Program Files\Application\INSTALL.LOG" Application Uninstall
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently installed a 32-bit program remotely & silently (thru PDQ) that utilizes Wise installer package and uninstalled the same program (via PDQ).

- The install was in a batch file using the full file path and its silent switch (`/S`)
- The uninstall was in a different batch file, but contained the short filename scheme (8.3).
- So the uninstall path was...

  `C:\PROGRA~2\YOUR-APP\UNWISE.EXE /S /Z C:\PROGRA~2\YOUR-APP\INSTALL.LOG`
- `/S` is silent
- `/Z` is to remove directories including itself
- No quotes used since there are no spaces, but it may not hurt if added

Hope this works for someone!

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Bill_Stewart, the vendor needs to answer this for you.  However, here's how to find your log:

1. run regedit
2. Navigate to HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
3. Find the AppName.
4. Examine the "UninstallString" key value

This will give you the log, but doesn't answer how to silently automate it.